# JS Regular expression to validate four digit space series, 1234 1234 124 1234

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to validate my user's input string in JS Regular expression, Users are allowed to enter `1234` or `1234 1234 1234 1234 1234` ...etc (separated by single space).

I am new to regex, i tried like this but didn't work.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+`

Comment: "but didn't worked" what didn't work? how didn't it work? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Do you mean exactly one or the other, or any number of repititions of `1234`? Also, do you mean exactly `1234` or do you mean any digit from 0-9 or even any group of four characters?

Comment: group of 4 characters, not only number

Comment: Presumably, non-whitesphce, non-punctuation, non-control characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final `+` only applies to the expression immediately before it. To apply it to everything from the `\s` onward, you need to add parentheses.

You can also simplify the expression by taking out the alternation and instead change the `+` to `*`, meaning zero or more repetitions.

Finally, add a `$` to the end to anchor the match to the end of the string, too. Otherwise you are checking whether the input string contains any prefix which matches your regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})*$
```

It doesn't matter much in this isolated case, but you might want to replace the opening parenthesis with `(?:` which avoids the overhead of collecting the substring which matches the parenthesized expression into a separate capture group. If you do this a lot, in a tight loop for example, the overhead could become significant.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(\s|$))*
```

See https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B4%7D%28%5Cs%7C%24%29%29*
[image]

Comment: Depending on how this is applied, this still only checks whether the input string contains a prefix which matches the regex.

Comment: You can switch final asterisk to a {x,} to repeat at least x times. e.g two times.
```^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(\s|$)){2,}```

Comment: For the record, that's spelled "asterisk". Asterix is a cartoon character.